# Android Compose resize image on available space

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm new to Android Jetpack Compose and have the following layout problem:

[image]

It's a simple example to clarify my issue. I want that Button header to stay on top and this two text areas at the bottom.
The image should take the rest of the available space, depending on the screen size. I don't want a scrollbar or white areas at the top/bottom.

At the moment the image has a fixed size. How do I have to adjust the layout so that the image automatically adapts to the available space?

Here's the code:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(32.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
        )
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "Back")
            }
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "Next")
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.waterfall), contentDescription = "Instant post demo image", Modifier.height(200.dp))
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
        Text(text = text, fontSize = 14.sp, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp))
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text(text = text, fontSize = 14.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Thx in advance

Comment: add `Modifier.weight(1f)` to your image

Comment: Seems to work for this simple example. My target layout is a little bit more complex. But based on your hint I was also able to solve my issue. 
So thank you!